# How to find p+q = sum, where p and q are distinct primes?

Tags: number-theory

I have been given $\phi(m)$ and $m = pq$.
Because $p$ and $q$ are primes, $\phi(m) = (p - 1)(q - 1)$
So I was able to find that $p+q$ = sum
But how do I find $p$ and $q$ after this?
The sum is larger than $23000$, so I do not know how to find $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\phi(m) = (p-1)(q-1) = pq - (p+q) + 1 = m - (p+q) + 1$$
Now solve a quadratic equation in $p$ (or $q$) to factor $m$:
$$(x-p)(x-q) = x^2 - (p+q)x + pq$$

Comment: With that quadratic equation what should I do? How do I find p and q using that quadratic equation?

Comment: @DorianFray What are its roots?